# Matching subjects with themselves when evaluating short term outcomes

Tags: experiment-design, causality, matching, causalimpact

I am considering a simple causal inference scenario; Let's say we want to examine the effect of paracetamol (treatment) on curing headache (outcome).

When performing matching, is it okay to match subject i with the same subject i in different cases where i used or not paracetamol - assuming that those two instances are far enough in time such that one instance is not interfering with the other?

Comment: I assume you want to get information about pain relief from each subject under two circumstances: (a) with drug and (b) without. There is always a possibility that whichever circumstance comes 1st will somehow influence the data collected on the 2nd. So it is best to give a randomly chosen half of the subjects the drug at the 1st session and half at the 2nd session. Then look for differences of with drug minus without. // As a check on carryover effect, also compare differences for drug-1st subjects with differences for drug-2nd subjects. If no difference, fine; if some, use amt to adjust.

Comment: so you first try to establish whether there is a carryover effect before assuming independence of the two sessions; If there is one you can either fallback to matching only sessions from different subjects or adjust the measured outcome knowing how much carryover there exists; Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Your last comment seems on track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BruceET is right in that you would need to first **verify there there is no carryover** effect in order to perform your suggested operations.

I do see in your question, you state the assumption that "those two instances are far enough in time such that one instance is not interfering with the other", by which you mean to assume there is no carryover effect. **Given this assumption, it would be valid to calculate the causal effect of the drug as the difference between the two instances.**

Also do note that if these treatments (and non-treatments) were **assigned rather than observed**, you may have to deal with non-compliance (people who were given the drug but do not take it, or people who were not given the drug and took it anyways, or people who took other drugs that may cure headache). You may consider calculating the [**Local Average Treatment Effect (LATE)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_average_treatment_effect) rather than the Average Treatment Effect (ATE).